# How to view .NET concurrent collections in WinDbg?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

Is there any efficient way how to view content of concurrent collections like `ConcurrentQueue`, `ConcurrentDictionary`, ... , `BlockingCollection` etc.?

There is a nice [extension netext](https://netext.codeplex.com/), but this can dump only old & good `Dictionary<..>` and `Hashtable`.

Honestly, I'm quite surprised that I didn't find any support for this as going through buckets, tails & heads in the instances is veery slow approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/default.aspx)' `!mdt` command seems quite ok if you have a WinDbg version that supports DML, because you can then click on the links to show and expand the arrays

ConcurrentQueue (note that `m_array` is a clickable link):

```
0:000> !mdt 000007fe959f4770 0000000002614660 -r:5
0000000002614660 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[[System.String, mscorlib]])
    m_head:0000000002614690 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1+Segment[[System.String, mscorlib]])
        m_array:00000000026146d0 (System.String[], Elements: 32)
        m_state:00000000026147e8 (System.Collections.Concurrent.VolatileBool[], Elements: 32, ElementMT=000007fef41022d8)
        m_next:NULL (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1+Segment[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]])
        m_index:0x0 (System.Int64)
        m_low:0x0 (System.Int32)
        m_high:0x9 (System.Int32)
        m_source:0000000002614660 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[[System.String, mscorlib]])
            <RECURSIVE>
    m_tail:0000000002614690 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1+Segment[[System.String, mscorlib]])
        m_array:00000000026146d0 (System.String[], Elements: 32)
        m_state:00000000026147e8 (System.Collections.Concurrent.VolatileBool[], Elements: 32, ElementMT=000007fef41022d8)
        m_next:NULL (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1+Segment[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]])
        m_index:0x0 (System.Int64)
        m_low:0x0 (System.Int32)
        m_high:0x9 (System.Int32)
        m_source:0000000002614660 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[[System.String, mscorlib]])
            <RECURSIVE>
    m_serializationArray:NULL (System.__Canon[])
    m_numSnapshotTakers:0x0 (System.Int32)

0:000> !mdt 00000000026146d0
00000000026146d0 (System.String[], Elements: 32)
expand all 32 items                                        <--- DML Link

0:000> !mdt -e:2 00000000026146d0
00000000026146d0 (System.String[], Elements: 32)
[0] 0000000002617508 "Hello WinDbg 0"
[1] 0000000002617670 "Hello WinDbg 1"
[2] 00000000026177d8 "Hello WinDbg 2"
[3] 0000000002617940 "Hello WinDbg 3"
[4] 0000000002617aa8 "Hello WinDbg 4"
[5] 0000000002617c10 "Hello WinDbg 5"
[6] 0000000002617d78 "Hello WinDbg 6"
[7] 0000000002617ee0 "Hello WinDbg 7"
[8] 0000000002618048 "Hello WinDbg 8"
[9] 00000000026181b0 "Hello WinDbg 9"
```

ConcurrentDictionary (note that `m_buckets` is a clickable link)

```
0:000> !mdt 0000000002614820 -r:6
0000000002614820 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]])
    m_tables:0000000002614eb0 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Tables[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]])
        m_buckets:0000000002614d98 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]][], Elements: 32)
        m_locks:00000000026148e8 (System.Object[], Elements: 32)
        m_countPerLock:0000000002614d00 (System.Int32[], Elements: 32)
        m_comparer:00000000026148d0 (System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[[System.String, mscorlib]])
    m_comparer:NULL (System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]])
    m_growLockArray:true (System.Boolean)
    m_keyRehashCount:0x0 (System.Int32)
    m_budget:0x1 (System.Int32)
    m_serializationArray:NULL (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]][])
    m_serializationConcurrencyLevel:0x0 (System.Int32)
    m_serializationCapacity:0x0 (System.Int32)

0:000> !mdt 0000000002614d98
0000000002614d98 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]][], Elements: 32)
expand all 32 items                                        <--- DML Link

0:000> !mdt -e:2 0000000002614d98
0000000002614d98 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]][], Elements: 32)
[...]
[18] 0000000002618148 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]])
    m_key:00000000026180b8 (System.String) Length=7, String="Hello 8"
    m_value:0000000002618118 (System.String) Length=8, String="WinDbg 8"
    m_next:NULL (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]])
    m_hashcode:0xd0fe55d2 (System.Int32)
[19] 00000000026182b0 (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]])
    m_key:0000000002618220 (System.String) Length=7, String="Hello 9"
    m_value:0000000002618280 (System.String) Length=8, String="WinDbg 9"
    m_next:NULL (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2+Node[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]])
    m_hashcode:0xd0fe55d3 (System.Int32)
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a look tomorrow. Still haven't heard about DML, I always learn something new :)

Comment: Might be useful, although it's not very friendly.. I'll accept this answer as it looks like there is nothing better right now.

Answer (score 1):

NetExt is now implementing !wconcurrentdict thanks to Mikhail Polgun code contribution.

```
!wconcurrentdict <address>
<address> - Address of the dictionary.

Examples:

Dumps a dictionary
------------------------
0:000> wconcurrentdict 00000001557d3920
Items   : 1
[0]:==============================================
System.__Canon key = 00000001557d2a70 CompilerVersion
System.__Canon value = 00000001557d2aa8 v2.0
```

Download the zip for NetExt here: https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext/tree/master/Binaries